# problems executing a jquery ajax call within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to put an ajax call within a function since I use it repeatedly in multiple locations.  I want a manipulated version of the response returned.  Here's what I'm trying to do (greatly simplified).

```
a = getAjax();
$('body').append('<div>'+a+'</div>');
function getAjax() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   success: function(response) {
     return response;
  });
}
```

What's happening, however, is that the append function is running before "a" has been defined in the getAjax function. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to taggle this. one is to use the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   success: function(response) {
     AppendResponse(response);
  });
```

the other is to set async to false http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

```
var a;
getAjax();
$('body').append('<div>'+a+'</div>');
function getAjax() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   async: false,
   success: function(response) {
     a = response;
  });
}
```

Important note on non async:

Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

Answer (score 16):

AJAX is asynchronous.  This means that the code in the success handler is delayed until the request is successful, while the rest of the code continues as normal.  You need to put the relevant code in the AJAX success handler:

```
getAjax();
function getAjax() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   success: function(response) {
     $(document.body).append('<div>'+response+'</div>');
  });
}
```

Note that I have also optimised your `body` selector by using the native Javascript `document.body` rather than using the standard tag selector.

---

**Edit** Callback version

```
function getAjax(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'someURL',
        success: callback
    });
}
```

You can now do the code inline using a callback function:

```
getAjax(function(response) {
    $(document.body).append('<div>'+response+'</div>');
});
```

or

```
getAjax(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

or whatever.

The code inside the anonymous function call will be processed when the AJAX request is complete.

Comment: just edit your code to replace 'a' in the success callback with 'response' since 'a' isn't defined

Comment: I could use that, but I don't always want to perform the same operations upon the successful ajax response. This is why I'd like to return the response.

Comment: Returning the response in this way is not what AJAX is designed for.  I have updated the answer with a way to provide a way to set what you want to happen when you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you return the response to another function in the success callback. This should handle your need for different responses:

```
getAjax();
function getAjax() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   success: function(response) {
     AppendResponse(response);
  });
}

function AppendResponse(response) {
$('body').append('<div>'+response+'</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion I have is to pass a trigger to the command you want to run into the AJAX function so that it will run after AJAX has received a response-

```
a = getAjax();
function getAjax() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   success: function(response) {
     inputText(response);
  });
}

inputText(someText) {
$(document.body).append('<div>'+ someText +'</div>');
}
```

That way you can create if statements / other alternatives to continue to use the same AJAX command for different results

Comment: FWIW, you could shorten this to `success: inputText`.  `inputText` is a reference to the function.  Not only anonymous functions can be used as callbacks!

Answer (score 0):

You can give a handler to the function `getAjax()`, but if the user needs the information for the next decision then why not wait using `async: false`?

```
function getAjax(handler) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'someURL',
   success: function(response) {
     handler(response);
  });
};
function callGetAjax(response) {
  if(response === undefined) {
    getAjax(callGetAjax);
  } else {
    $('body').append('<div>'+response+'</div>');
  }
}
```